# Button over map Xamarin forms

Tags: google-maps, xaml, button, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms to write my application.
I would like to add a button above my map (red circle in the picture) to open another page: [go to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksVMT.png)

This is the code I wrote on the xaml page:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="search.png" Clicked="SearchClicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

 <ContentView Content="{Binding Map}" ></ContentView>
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position a button over a page's content I would look at an [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout). You should be able to do something like the following in XAML.

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <ContentView Content="{Binding Map}" 
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
  <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
          HeightRequest="50"
          WidthRequest="50"
          CornerRadius="25" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

This is untested and may need some tweaking, but should give you something to build off of.

Comment: It works! I used AbsoluteLayout but it didn't work. Your solution is ok, thanks!

Comment: @Riccardo what solution you did to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Xamarin.Forms.Maps`, you could implement the following (or similar):

```xml
<Grid
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <map:Map
        IsShowingUser="True"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        MapType="Hybrid"/>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!-- Insert your circle control below. Using BoxView as example -->
        <BoxView
            AbsoluteLayout.AbsoluteBounds="0.1, 0.9, 20, 20"
            AbsoluteLayout.AbsoluteFlags="PositionProportional"
            BackgroundColor="Red">
            <BoxView.GestureRecognizer>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="OnCircleTap"/> <!-- Replace with your event -->
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizer/>
        </BoxView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Grid>
```